# Why is the savedInstanceState Bundle I pass to my Android Fragment empty on arrival?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-activity

In the Android app I am developing I have a list fragment that shows a `RecyclerView` of list items. The first time we open the fragment it retrieves the list from a url, but it's not going to change frequently enough to keep reloading it so I want to retain the data. As far as I can tell the Android way to do this is using the `savedInstanceState` for the fragment, like this:

```
class ItemListFragment() {

    private var itemCards: RecyclerView? = null;

        public val Items: ArrayList<Item> = ArrayList<Item>()

    override fun onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState)
        if ( Items.size == 0 && savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey("items")) {
            val arrayType = object: TypeToken<Array<Item>>() {}.type
            val tempItems: Array<Item> = Gson().fromJson(savedInstanceState.getString("items"), arrayType)
            Items.addAll(tempItems)
        }
    }

}
```

Then I manage the states in my `MainActivity` like this:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

        private lateinit var restoreBundle: HashMap<String, Bundle>

        private var currentFragment = ""

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            restoreBundle = HashMap<String, Bundle>()
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

   override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
            // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
            drawFragment(item.itemId)
   }

        private fun drawFragment(position:Int) {
            val fragMan: FragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager()
            val fragmentName = getFragmentName(position)
            val bundle:Bundle = restoreBundle.get(fragmentName) ?: Bundle()

            var fragment: Fragment? =   fragMan.getFragment(bundle, fragmentName)

            if ( fragment == null ) {
                fragment =  ItemListFragment() as Fragment
            }

            val current = fragMan.findFragmentByTag(currentFragment)

            if (current != null) {
                    val frag = getFragmentName(current.id)
                    val recover : Bundle =  restoreBundle.get(frag) ?: Bundle()
                    current.onSaveInstanceState(recover)
                    restoreBundle.set(frag, recover);
            }


                if (fragmentSet) {
                    fragMan.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.main_content_fragment, fragment!!, fragmentName).commit()
                } else {
                    fragMan.beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.main_content_fragment, fragment!!, fragmentName).commit()
                }
            currentFragment = fragmentName

        }
}
```

Both of these examples have been trimmed down to what seems to me the relevant parts but the code may not be the problem so much as what I am trying to do. Basically when I switch fragment a couple of times and it calls  `fragMan.getFragment(bundle, fragmentName)` the `bundle` contains the correct saved instance state but when I get into `ItemListFragment.onViewStateRestored` ( which is the next place I can put a breakpoint as far as I can tell ) the `savedInstanceState` bundle is null.

Why is the bundle I am passing in not the same as the one being retrieved *or* what is the correct way to pass the instance state to my fragment?

Comment: You should use viewmodel for preserve data instead of onrestoreinstncestate(), there is a restriction on data, in this case, If that data limit exceeds, it throws transactiontoolarge exception

Comment: @akashzincle It's just some viewmodels I'm stashing in the fragment bundle now - is there an better way to pass that in at fragment instantiation?

Comment: Well the change I will suggest, might be a bigger change, What you can do is , take on Activity Level ViewModel, In this ViewModel, Keep data required for every fragment on their first API call, Now whenever a fragment is attached again, You don't need to pass anything, Just pull the data from activity viewmodel in the fragment, as All the fragments attached to activity can access its activityViewModel directly, I think first you should read a little more about viewmodels , would be better to start with.

Comment: @akashzincle As I said, I'm using a viewmodel, but ideally I would prefer to keep data that is only relevant to a specific fragment in the fragment - I feel like holding it in the activity at all is excessive, but it seems like there is no way for fragments to maintain their own state. If I need to handle it elsewhere then a service might make sense, but I don't want to build that scaffolding if there is a built in system for managing it.

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a satisfactory answer to this, so I adjusted my architecture so that the models were loaded from - and stored in - their own service and made accessible as part of a companion object in my `MainActivity` rather than attempting to use the Fragment architecture to pass data into the fragment. It is not clear that the latter is possible, regardless of what the documentation suggests.